# Is this kind of constructor injection recommended?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection

Lets say you have an object called `ServicesProvider` which his role is to provide services. It will provide services objects such as Mailer, Logger and CacheService.

For those that tend to say it's breaking the Single Responsibility Principle, how does it break it? Its role is only to provide services, it doesn't do more than one thing since his responsibility is to provide services objects.

Here is the code:

```
public class ServicesProvider : IServicesProvider {
   // Properties...
   public ServicesProvider(
       ICacheService cacheService, 
       ILoggerService loggerService, 
       IMailerService mailerService) { ... }
}
```

Is it recommended to inject this object to any business classes that need services? If not, why? What's the recommended approach to solve this problem, please provide a complete example?

Comment: Injecting an `IServiceProvider` into other classes, is (still) called the Service Locator pattern, which is considered to be bad. Read Here more about this: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx.

Comment: @Rushino: I've noticed that you've been asking a lot of questions about DI recently. That's fine and you are welcome to keep doing that. However, if you would prefer a coherent treatment of the topic, you *could* read my book ;) http://affiliate.manning.com/idevaffiliate.php?id=1150_236

Comment: @MarkSeemann Haha. Yeah i could offcourse, do not worry i am probably the dude that would read most of the books out there.. but time isnt on my side unfortunally :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're aggregating all possible dependencies in a single object and then each class instead of requiring only the dependencies needed, requires an object that knows how to get all the dependencies. If you are going this root, you might as well drop the dependency injection part and just use the service locator pattern directly.

Going this way, you hide the real requirements of your classes, for example you can't know if a class only requires `ICacheService` just by looking at its constructor because it receives an `IServiceProvider` that allows her to request any service at any point of its life cycle.

As I said, what you're trying to do is pretty similar to using the service locator pattern so you can research about the pros and cons of using dependency injection vs service locator to satisfy an inversion of control requirement.

Comment: How about at least inject them (each of the services) in a base class ?

Comment: If all the services are required for every class inheriting from that base class than it makes sense to require the services at the base class level.

Comment: that being said.. if one class do not use theses features then there no reason to have a base class then.

Comment: Using base classes will require that you pass all dependencies to the base class, as well as any dependencies a derived class may require. This can lead to some pretty ugly constructors. *Favor composition over inheritance.*

Comment: Or you can use property injection in the base class. I find this a usable option when i have a large group of usually small classes that need the same set of dependencies (such as command handlers).This lowers the overhead of constructor injection.

Comment: @Steven No! Dont sweep constructor over-injection smells under the carpet using technical tricks - expanded version of this comment https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns

Comment: @Ruben: With great power... We always should be at the look-out for violations of the SRP and ctor over-injection is often an indication of this. I'm not saying base property injection is always the way to go. But you are right, my advice is perhaps a bit tricky, because it is easy to abuse and overuse this technique. I would only advice this technique in just a handful of cases, as the case I described above. Another option is the use of an Aggregate Service. However, the downside of this, is that it makes the code less clean, because we have to write `this.aggregate.Db` instead of `this.Db`.

Comment: More info about [Aggregate Services](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringToAggregateServices.aspx).

Comment: @Steven. While your general point is fine, I dont believe Mark is for one second suggesting exposing the properties for each component of the aggregate - so if the only objection is that you need to dot through more stuff (implying which aspect of the aggregate an action pertains to) that's only a good thing (always watching out for Law of Demeter implications). Also, each portion of the facade will naturally cluster around the aspects covered - people other than me would even start thinking about #regions :D

Comment: Picky: While @Mark Seemann isnt changing the URL, he has internally retitled Aggregate services __Facade Services__ - the pattern isnt to interpret favouring Composition over Inheritance as just meaning a cluster of components globbed together.

Comment: @Ruben: Yeah, #regions... we all love those ;-)